# Use Active Directory Web Services in Windows 8 Store App

Tags: c#, web-services, xaml, active-directory, windows-8.1

I have a windows 8 app that I need to authenticate my users. I saw this article on ADWS and I haven't been able to find out if this can be used in Windows 8 store apps (or metro apps).

http://samirvaidya.blogspot.de/2012/06/using-active-directory-web-services-in.html

If not I need to find another source to access AD through my app.

Thanks for the help!